# Selecting data where field is null or with query builder Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to select data from database where id_parent is not null or child is more than zero with query builder Yii. So, I am writing my script like below.`

```
$parent = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('*')
                    ->from('parameter')
                    ->where( 'id_parent = null or child >0' )
                    ->order('laboratorium', 'ASC')
                    ->queryAll();
```

It gives me result just 2 rows of data. Both of them have id_parent is null and child is more than zero. I need data not only that but also data were id_parent is null although its child is zero.
In the other case, I want to select data from same table with id_parent is not null. I use this script:

```
$child = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                    ->select('*')
                    ->from('parameter_pemeriksaan')
                    ->where('id_parent != null')
                    ->queryRow();
```

And the result is array(0){} since I have several data in my database with id_parent is not null. 
How I solve it?

Comment: Why you used `->queryRow();` use `->queryAll();` in second query. Check once.

Comment: what field type `id_parent` and `child` does have?

Comment: @Nana I already try it but the result is array(0)

Comment: @Chetan type of id_parent and child are INT

Comment: try `->where( 'id_parent is null or child >0' )`

Comment: when using null you should use is like: id_parent IS NULL , id_parent IS NOT NULL

Comment: Thanks. It is working with your script

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong comparison to `NULL`. Use `IS NULL`/`IS NOT NULL` to check if entry is/is not null. Check [this resource](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html) about NULL comparison.

So your condition must be:

```
`id_parent` IS NULL OR `child` > 0
`id_parent` IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: It is solved. my condition is
where('id_parent is null or child > 0')

Comment: and
where(' id_parent is not null').
But thanks\ you very much for trying to help me. :)